# facing the below issue while setting thoughput in packer json file, need help to resolve this issue

Tags: json, packer

Error:
Template validation failed. Errors are shown below.

Errors validating build 'amazon-ebs'. 1 error(s) occurred:

- unknown configuration key: "launch_block_device_mappings[0].throughput"

script returned exit code 1

Code:
"launch_block_device_mappings": [
{
"device_name": "/dev/sda1",
"volume_size": 40,
"volume_type": "gp2",
"volume_size": 80,
"volume_type": "gp3",
"throughput": 270,
"delete_on_termination": true"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and I updated my packer version to 1.6.6 and that worked.